# Syntax error near unexpected token ` "Hello World!" ' on Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I'm starting to learn Linux and I wanted to create myself an python file with simple line of code which is

`print("Hello World")`

Running the file in terminal gives me [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFr9L.png) that I cannot fix which says

`` Syntax error near unexpected token ` "Hello World!" ' ``

I tried adding \ and / next to parenthesis but it didn't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: Does it change if you execute it via 'python file1.py' command on terminal?

Comment: You should run it as `python file1.py` not using `./` unless you specify the interpreter path in the script.

Comment: Which is to say: Your first line should be something like `#!/usr/bin/env python`; otherwise your shell will assume that the script is a shell script, and run it with a shell instead of with a Python interpreter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error comes from bash, not Python. As if you were to type `print("Hello World")` in your terminal. Try running the python file as `python3 file3.py`.